# "Merge tags" tool is broken

Tags: bug

I tried to merge [plant](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant) into [botany](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/botany) using the mod-only tag merge tool and I get an "Oops! Something Bad Happened!".

I tried the tool on Skeptics and it worked fine. Checking or unchecking the "also create a synonym" option does not change anything, I always get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the [proposed synonym](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) from [botany](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/botany) to [plant](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant); if you delete that - it should work OK.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after I removed the synonym suggestion.